# Changing the text of buttons generated by RecycleView in Kivy

Tags: python, kivy

I am not very experienced with Kivy, and have been trying to read the documentation, but I keep getting stuck.

I have a list ["1", "2", "3", "4", "5"] which I would like to use to generate buttons and display them using RecycleView. Due to aesthetic reasons, I do not want to show these values, but would like to simply display "One", "Two", "Three", "Four", "Five" on the buttons instead. However I would require the ["1", "2", "3", "4", "5"] to be still used as I would like the values to be referenced to later when I click on the generated buttons.

I have tried adding text: "One" under the ListResultsButton class to play around with the syntax, but somehow it is still showing the values in the list.

I would be grateful if anyone can help me with a method to **show alternative text on the generated buttons, and even better if I can display text from a second list on the buttons** while generating the buttons from the first list.

I have included a diagram to better visualise my problem.
[Diagram that shows the problem](https://i.stack.imgur.com/4qivR.png)

Python code and kv code:

```
from kivy.app import App
from kivy.uix.boxlayout import BoxLayout
from kivy.properties import ObjectProperty

test_list = ["1", "2", "3", "4", "5"]

class Test2Root(BoxLayout):

    show_list_input = ObjectProperty()

    def show_list(self):
        #update data in recycleview
        self.show_list_input.data = [{'text': str(x)} for x in test_list]

class Test2App(App):
    pass

if __name__ == "__main__":
    Test2App().run()
```

```
#kv code
Test2Root:

<Test2Root>:
    show_list_input: show_list_input_ID
    orientation: "vertical"

    Button:
        text: "Press Me"
        on_press: root.show_list()

    RecycleView:
        id: show_list_input_ID
        viewclass: 'ListResultsButton'
        data: []

        RecycleBoxLayout:
            orientation: 'vertical'
            default_size: None, dp(25)
            default_size_hint: 1, None
            size_hint_y: None
            height: self.minimum_height

<ListResultsButton@Button>
    text: "One"
```

I would really appreciate any help. Thank you!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I don't have experience with Kivy. But, looking at the code, I believe the following will work:

```py
from kivy.app import App
from kivy.uix.boxlayout import BoxLayout
from kivy.properties import ObjectProperty

test_list = ["1", "2", "3", "4", "5"]
# Add text in an array
btns_text = ["One", "Two", "Three", "Four", "Five"]

class Test2Root(BoxLayout):

    show_list_input = ObjectProperty()

    def show_list(self):
        #update data in recycleview
        # Change it like this
        self.show_list_input.data = [{'text': btns_text[x]} for x in range(len(test_list))]

class Test2App(App):
    pass

if __name__ == "__main__":
    Test2App().run()
```

Comment: Hi. Thanks for the reply. I was actually looking for a method to store the values from the first list as a property in the button generated.

Comment: Not sure if that is possible. But, I can suggest a workaround. You can create a dictionary to save key value pairs. For example, `{'1': 'One', ...}`. Then, you can display **values** as button text and use **keys** for calculations or whatever you want.